# Разный HTML результат по одной и той же ссылке через Android приложение и браузер

Tags: java, android, html, http, jsoup

Есть вот такая ссылка http://moscow.megafon.ru/corporate/

Если вы подключены к интернету через *4G* этого оператора, то на верху будет высвечен номер телефона.

На планшете захожу в браузер *Chrome*, ввожу эту ссылку и показывается номер телефона.

В моем приложении, через *Jsoup* (а так же пробовал через *HttpGet* от *org.apach*), я получаю содержание странички, и если так же при помощи этого *Jsoup* сделать парсинг, то  номера не будет.

То есть ощущение, что в запрос браузер вкладывает какую-то доп информацию, которая помогает серверной стороне *Megafon*'а определить мой номер.

Но что может такого вложить браузер?

Я посмотрел хедер и куки при отправке запроса и эти же куки тупо вставил при отправке через *Jsoup*, но результат разный.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а Вы все хедеры подставляете правильно? с другой стороны, никто не мешает браузеру сделать запрос на получение номера с помощью javascript. В этом случае JSoup ничего не покажет.


Сам зайти на этот сайт не могу. Видимо он только для пользователей Мегафона.

Comment: Как сказал @KoVadim. Если там запрос через javascript, то получить эту инфу никак нельзя будет. Разве что если в приложении использовать вместо стандартного клиента webclient с редиректом джава запросов. Но это тяжеловесно